# Executing jar from q

Tags: cmd, system, kdb

I'm trying to run an executable jar from a `q` process but it gets stuck loading (no error).

When running the jar from `cmd` it works fine.

In cmd:

```
java -cp "C:/javaWorkspaces/someDirectory/myJar.jar" myPackage.myClass
```

In q:

```
system "java -cp \"C:/javaWorkspaces/someDirectory/myJar.jar\" myPackage.myClass"
```

Also note that the jar uses external jars (packaged with eclipse), creates a new thread and connects to the internet. It seems like the latter might be the problem (after doing some manual `sysout` debugging)

What can I do about this?

Comment: Can you give more details please, otherwise we're just guessing. What line were you running on the cmd line? What line were you trying to run in q?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the -jar flag when running the jar? Aside from that, try putting the command in a script and run the script from a `system` call

Comment: @user2393012 Don't need to use the `-jar` flag if you specify the package. When using the script approach, do I still escape the backslashes?

Comment: no need for backslashes, if you put the command in a script and make sure it runs from command line by itself then just call the script, e.g. `system"/home/me/script.sh"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by writing a small Java program that executes the full `java` command in `cmd`:

```
q -> runs small Java program 1 -> runs cmd commands to open the dependent Java class
```

I think the problem was that the `jar` had external dependencies which also needed to be loaded, eventhough Eclipse says it 'packs' them together with the jar.

I think a plugin such as [Fat Jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) is the solution for creating an independent executable jar.

But I didn't care about creating a fully independent jar. This solution works evenly well. It's a bit of a workaround but the final code in q is now much cleaner and shorter.